# React native redux-persist problem in snack.expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo, redux-persist

I'm trying to try a project that uses redux on snack.expo, but I get the following error:

> Device: (1179:881) Unable to resolve module 'module://redux-persist/integration/react.js'
>         Evaluating module://redux-persist/integration/react.js
>         Evaluating module://store/addStore.js.js
>         Evaluating module://App.js.js
>         Loading module://App.js

How can I solve the problem so I can also try it on snack.expo.

Link: [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/r14pSsj1r)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `redux-persist` as dependency in your package.json file.

Hint : alternatively open `store/store.js` and you should see at the bottom left of your screen a snack notification, asking you if you want to add this dependency to the snack.

Comment: The problem does not seem to work up snack.expo.
can you give me a hand